# FILE-ACCESS Reading images previously written to NSDocumentDirectory FAILS

Tags: ios, file-io, ios5

Having recently downloaded and installed XCode 4.3 from the App Store, I find a **serious and unexpected** problem when reading image-files (large JPEG files)  previously stored in the application User Documents. The issue is as follows:

(i) The files derive from the user's photo-library and the UIcropped original image ( `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`) is correctly stored to User Documents. Inspection of the User Documents folder shows the image file correctly stored. Copying this file to my user-account creates a copy that can be loaded (for example) into the Preview application or else iPhoto. The expected image is loaded by Preview and iPhoto and can be seen to be visually correct.

(ii) On attempting to read the stored file with the standard method

```
UIImage * image = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: file ]
```

method (where file is the full path-name of the stored file) the image returned is nil. nil is also returned on attempting an `NSData`  load via

```
NSData * data = [ NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: file options: 
NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error: & error ];
```

In this case the full `NSError *`  error object is reported as follows:

```
CODE= 260, DOMAIN= NSCocoaErrorDomain, 
USERINFO = 
{ NSFilePath = "<User Documents>/<filename>.jpeg";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain 
Code=2 \"The operation couldn't be completed. No such file or directory\"";
}
```

(iii) Examining the copied file in Finder shows that the "Kind" of the previousl;y written image-file is now "Document" wheras previously it was (as expected) "JPEG Image". This is the ONLY evident problem with the file.

(iv) Replacing the previous written file with an externally created JPEG image file WITH EXACTLY THE SAME NAME results in a successful loading of the file via  [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: file ]!

THIS LOOKS, THEREFORE, TO BE A PERMISSIONS PROBLEM RATHER THAN A JPEG-DATA PROBLEM. New with XCode 4.3 installation is the Kind= "Document" replacing the previous (and working) Kind = "JPEG Image". CAN ANYONE PLEASE THROW LIGHT ON THIS MATTER AND IF POSSIBLE ADVISE A SOLUTION? The matter is urgent & frustrating for me as it breaks a PDF design tool under urgent development!

Best Wishes,
 Negative Entropy

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug and "po file" from the console? I've not seen a permission problem before, so I suspect the path. Also, we have seen issues with case sensitivity (iOS is case sensitive, whereas your Simulator may not be). Need to see the full `path` variable contents.